# Boolean modifier messes up material assignment

Tags: materials, modifiers

I have a car that has two materials assigned to it. When I apply a boolean modifier to the car it tweaks all the colors that were assigned to it.

Why is this and what can I do about it?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE BlendSwap :). Your question appears to be a bug report and it is not exactly clear what you are asking either. Can you please clarify by adding an image to the post. Also, please see this [post on what to do with possible bugs](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports).

Answer (score 3):

This is because assigning different materials to a mesh is dependent on the *Topology* of the mesh.

Adding a Boolean operation changes the topology, so the faces that no longer exist can't have a material, and new faces will most likely be in different positions or shapes.

Blender assigns the first material to new faces created by a Boolean modifier:

[image: boolean example] [image: materials]

A few possible workarounds:

1. Applying the Boolean modifier and assigning the materials your self, as well as changing the topology to fit where the materials should go.
2. Using a texture to combine materials with a [Mix shader](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Shaders#Mix_and_Add), independent of the object topology.

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: Here is the source for material assignment: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Booleans.
"the modified mesh will receive its first active material index assigned to its new topology"