# Cannot assign material to the correct face

Tags: materials, mirror

When I select the face and press "assign material", the material isn't assigned to the face but somehow to parts of it and parts outside of it...

How can I assign a material to this face?
[image]

Comment: Avoid triangles and n-gons, when subdivided they have this king of behavior.

Comment: you have a subsurf modifier which will change the topology

Comment: btw, this might not be an answer to your question, but I think you could make this spaceship look way cooler when you add an *edge split* modifier and mark some sharp edges with ctrl+e.

Comment: Man I understood NOTHING xD skype: Omnitored

Comment: So someone can help me?

Comment: The underlying topology is being changed by some modifiers (related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2172/599). The area the material is assigned to is defined by the topology, so it's affected by the modifiers

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with two issues: non-planar geometry and the interpolation generated by the subsurf modifier.

Let's start with the second.

The subsurf modifier is designed to make things rounder by subdividing the existing faces and make them smoother. If the faces are too big for the complex shapes you are trying to achieve, you'll see artifacts.

[image]

The solution is to edit your mesh with a bit more density so that the shapes are better described. Then the subsurf modifier will not be interpolating the surfaces and it's materials in such a drastic way.

[image]

Now, for an explanation of how to deal with non-planar geometry read [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23602/1853)

Comment: Turned off subsurf, but then the ship looks all different. How do you make those double lines like on the gif. nr. 2?

Comment: using the loop cut tool http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24419/1853

Comment: NOOOOPE, almost everything works but ofcourse there is 1 bug.. http://prntscr.com/88comd Help me fix it? Tryed both ways

Comment: For different questions please make a new post.