# Materials not lining up properly with an edge

Tags: materials, subdivision-surface

I'm trying here to put two materials on one mesh, but the material doesn't line up the way i want it to be:

[image]

I want the line between red and white to line up with the blue line. How to I do that?

Note that subdivision surface modifier messes that up here.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36221/cannot-assign-material-to-the-correct-face/36279#36279

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84158/material-showing-on-wrong-faces/84160#84160

Comment: Thanks! Those links helped me, suprising that I didn't notice myself i could just add more loop cuts there.